# Undefined behaviour during compile time and run time

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I still can't pinpoint exactly on which level undefined behaviour is actually defined. Assume the following code:

```
int i = value;
unsigned int x = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
```

This is valid C++ code and defined if e.g. `i` is `1`. But on `i = -1` it becomes undefined behaviour, so the application is in UB state during runtime.

In the code sample below UB is already apparent during compile time. So my question is, is it correct that UB can be either during compile time or runtime? What is the correct terminology here?

```
void foo(int* p)
{
    int v = *p;
    if (p == nullptr)
        return;
}
```

Comment: In both cases it's not necessarily UB, only if the statements are actually executed.

Comment: There's no undefined behavior for `i = -1`. Overflow during *arithmetic* leads to undefined behavior. But a cast has a well defined meaning here.

Comment: @aschepler: it is, see post of duDE, it extends to even parsing which quite answers my question

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That sounds reasonable but latter example actually creates false code by compilers since an optimizer assumes it can never be true so UB must have an impact on compile time

Comment: OP, you misunderstand. Compile-time UB, also known as "ill-formed NDR", can happen if the condition for the UB to happen involves the program text rather than the program execution. However, run-time UB cannot occur at compile-time because the program has to actually be executed in order to determine whether the run-time evaluation that is UB actually occurs or not.

Comment: @Brian So latter example is actually NDR, but not UB? Means NDR leads to UB but is not UB

Comment: The second example is well-formed, and is not guaranteed to cause UB, because it's possible that `foo` will only be called with non-null pointers.

Comment: There are some requirements which definitely could be diagnosed at compile time but are still described as UB, not ill-formed (with or without NDR).

Comment: I do not understand example 1, casting int a to unsigned int b is defined behavior for all values of a since unsigned integers shall obey the laws of modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Öö Tilb the value - 1 cannot be represented by an unsigned int

Comment: @DanielStephens -- yes, the value -1 cannot be represented by an unsigned int. But the result of **converting** that value to `unsigned int` is well defined. As an earlier comment said, unsigned integers obey the laws of modular arithmetic. So the result is the largest value that an `unsigned int` can hold.